# What does isConcurrent mean for NSOperation running from NSOperationQueue?

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

Because `NSOperationQueue` always run tasks on a new thread,
I'm confused about the role of `isConcurrent` when `NSOperation` runs from `NSOperationQueue`.

If i have two subclasses of `NSOperation`, both running an async processes, both are launched from `NSOperationQueue` and in both I override `isCancelled`, `isExecuting`, `isFinished` and `isReady`.
What will be the difference if at one I override `isConcurrent` to always `return YES` and the other always to `return NO`.

Who actually calls `isConcurrent`? How the logic change if it is `NO` or `YES`.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? It seems like this is pretty thoroughly explained.

Comment: I've tried to add a more concise answer given the discussion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a legacy method, used before OS X v10.6 and before iOS 4, i.e. before the introduction of GCD for `NSOperationQueue` dispatch.

From the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperation)

> Operation queues usually provide the threads used to run their operations. In OS X v10.6 and later, operation queues use the `libdispatch` library (also known as Grand Central Dispatch) to initiate the execution of their operations. As a result, operations are **always executed on a separate thread**, regardless of whether they are designated as concurrent or non-concurrent operations. **In OS X v10.5, however, operations are executed on separate threads only if their `isConcurrent` method returns `NO`**. If that method returns YES, the operation object is expected to create its own thread (or start some asynchronous operation); the queue does not provide a thread for it.

If you're running OS X >= 10.6 or iOS >= 4, you can safely ignore it.

As a confirmation of this fact, from the doc of [`isConcurrent`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperation)

> In OS X v10.6 and later, operation queues **ignore the value** returned by this method and always start operations on a separate thread.

Comment: I down voted this this answer because I don't think that it's main conclusion that `isConcurrent` can safely be ignored after 10.6 or iOS4 is correct, given that the method has not been deprecated.

Comment: Is not deprecated because you don't invoke the method, your override it. This method is called by Apple internal implementation of `NSOperationQueue` and they explicitly say that they are going to ignore its return value.

Comment: I don't see the link between invoking vs overriding and deprecating. The quotes from the documentation show one change in how the method is used now vs in the past.  I don't think that means it couldn't change again in the future, or isn't used anywhere else, and so you should just ignore it.  I think until it is deprecated you should return the correct answer, even if you suspect it's not currently used.

Answer (score 2):

I have added a more concise answer now, left this for the time being as it was part of a discussion...

---

Ok, I was quite happy with my use of the `isConcurrent` method until today !

I read the sentence:

> In OS X v10.6 and later, operation queues ignore the value returned by
>   this method and always start operations on a separate thread.

As a warning relating to QA1712, pointing out that for concurrent operations the `start` method can now be called on a different thread to the one that queued the operation, which is a change in 10.6 and iOS 4.

I didn't read this as indicating that the `isConcurrent` method is ignored completely by the queue and has no purpose at all, just that it no longer effects the thread on which `start` is called.  I may have misunderstood this.

I also misunderstood the original question as a more general one about concurrent operations and the `isConcurrent` flag, and the accepted answer as effectively saying

> The `isConcurrent` flag can be ignored since 10.6 and iOS 4

I'm not sure this is correct.

If I understand the original question now, to paraphrase:

> Given a **correctly** built concurrent `NSOperation` does the `isConcurrent` flag itself actually alter the execution of the operation at all?

I guess it's hard to say for all possible setups, but we can say that:

1. It's not deprecated.  It's normal for Apple to deprecate methods
   that are no longer useful.
2. The documentation consistently refers to the method being a required
   override.

Perhaps `isConcurrent` is effectively deprecated but as it's only a single `BOOL` flag perhaps it's not worth the effort to deprecate it in the docs.  Or perhaps it does nothing now but Apple have kept it for possible future use and expect you to override it as described.

I created a quick test project with an `NSOperation` that overrode `isConcurrent` and `main` only, `isConcurrent` was not called at any stage.  It was a very simple test though.  I assume you may have tested it also?  I assumed perhaps if the `NSOperationQueue` didn't call it `NSOperation's` default implementation of `start` might.

So where does that leave us? Obviously it's no trouble to implement it and return `YES` to satisfy the documented requirements.  However from my perspective I think it's too much of a leap to go from the caveat regarding 10.6 and iOS 4.0 to say that it can be safely ignored now.

---

**My Original Answer...**

`isConcurrent` is not a legacy method and is not ignored by `NSOperationQueue`.  The documentation as quoted in the other answers is a little unclear and easily misunderstood.

`isConcurrent = YES` means the operation provides its own means of concurrency.  Or to put it another way, the operation `"isAlreadyConcurrent"` and doesn't need the `NSOperationQueue` to provide and manage the concurrency. As `NSOperationQueue` is no longer providing the concurrency you need to tell it when the operation `isFinished` or if it `isCancelled` (etc) hence the need to override these methods.

A common example is an `NSOperation` that manages an `NSURLConnection`.  `NSURLConnection` has it's own mechanism for running in the background, so doesn't need to be made concurrent by `NSOperationQueue`.

An obvious question is then: "Why put an already concurrent operation into an `NSOperationQueue`?"  It's so the operation can benefit from the other features of the `NSOperationQueue` like dependencies etc.

The misleading part of the documentation is referring only to what thread the `start` method of an `NSOperation` is called on.  The change caused a problem discussed in QA1712.

Comment: I got that from the documentation, but this does not answer my question. Under the assumption that i override all NSOperation methods and i run it under NSOperationQueue, how does setting isConcurrent to YES or NO make a difference?

Comment: You say "and is not ignored by NSOperationQueue" so why does the documentation say "operation queues ignore the value returned by this method"?

Comment: Hi David, added some explanation of how I interpreted that quote in the docs.  I think the docs are confusing, but I may just be confusing myself :-).  I'm still not sure given the lack of formal deprecation and it's use in the rest of the documentation that is is safe to just ignore `isConcurrent` after 10.6 and iOS4...

Answer (score 0):

Paraphrasing the original question to:

> Given a correctly built concurrent `NSOperation` does the value returned by `isConcurrent` actually alter the execution of the operation at all?

Whilst we could try to understand how the `isConcurrent` flag is used by `NSOperation`, `NSOperationQueue`, or other parts of the operating system, it would be a mistake to rely on any information we discovered.

The purpose of the flag is described only as:

> Return YES if the operation runs asynchronously with respect to the current thread or NO if the operation runs synchronously on whatever thread started it.

As long as you correctly respond, it should not be important who calls the method or how it effects any logic inside the Apple frameworks.

---

***Additional Notes:***

The documentation does make reference to a change in the way that `NSOperationQueue` used this value before and after OSX 10.6 and iOS 4.0.

> In OS X v10.6, operation queues ignore the value returned by isConcurrent and always call the start method of your operation from a separate thread. In OS X v10.5, however, operation queues create a thread only if isConcurrent returns NO. ...

This change caused an issue described in [QA1712](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1712/_index.html).

This commentary is commonly interpreted to imply that the `isConcurrent` flag is no longer used after 10.6 and iOS 4, and can be ignored.  I do not agree with this interpretation as the method has not been formally deprecated and is still documented as a required override for concurrent operations.

Also the fact that it's use has changed in the past is a reminder that it could change again in the future, so we should respond correctly even if we suspect it does not currently have any effect.